# "Я и мой друг" or "мы с моим другом"?

Tags: грамматика

Is there a difference in meaning between theses two?—I assume that there is. What is the difference? When should one structure be used and not the other?

For example:

"Я и мой друг встретились перед обедом."

"мы с моим другом встретились перед обедом."

Comment: You can also say: "Я с моим другом встретился .."

Comment: But that means "I met him", and not "He and I met" /\ "me and him met". Does "я и мой друг встретились" means something like the ungrammatical "me and my friend did x"? In english one can say this but it's not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms are correct. Yet "Я и мой друг" seems to have a little accent on the previous separation, while "Мы с моим другом" sounds just neutral. You may think it as being somewhat close (at least in the specific context) to simple past vs present perfect tense in English.

```
Мы с моим другом встретились --> We met

Я и мой друг встретились --> We have met
```

UPD. As an example of usage. *После долгих лет разлуки я и мой друг наконец-то встретились*. That's mostly stylistical difference "*we*" vs "*me and him*".

Comment: @ user4419802 Could you give me a few examples of where one form would be preferred? Thanks.

Comment: Agree that both forms are correct. The last two sentences are nonsense. -1

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. Both *"Я и мой друг"* and *"Мы с моим другом"* mean same thing. Try to give us a context where these two are not the same in your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is pure logical.

Let us
`We = my sister and I`
Then

```
"Я и мой друг встретились перед обедом."       is incorrect for this situation

"Мы с моим другом встретились перед обедом."      OK

"Мы с моими друзьями встретились перед обедом."   OK
```

Let us
`We = my friend and I`
Then

```
"Я и мой друг встретились перед обедом."          OK
 \___мы_____/

"Мы с моим другом встретились перед обедом."      OK
    \___________/
         |
          limiting attribute

"Мы с моими друзьями встретились перед обедом."   incorrect
```

Comment: Please explain: `"Я и мой друг встретились перед обедом." is incorrect for this situation`

Comment: @JacobSeleznev , The meaning of *"я и мой друг"* shall be solely the meaning of *"tête-a-tête"*. After *"мы с мои другом ..."*, if it were happening at trial, for example, it is nearly certain that will be followed by a question: *Вы(ед.ч) были один? "You were alone with him?"*

Answer (score 1):

The most common is:

> Перед обедом я встретился с другом.

Also:

> Мы с другом встретились перед обедом.

The word "моим" is unnecessary here.